# Default value not updating on "Add Part"

Tags: qgis

I have a default value setup on a column in QGIS to calculate the area of a polygon. I also checked "Apply default value on update".
This works if I add a polygon or change the vertexes.

[image: Default Attribute]

If I add a polygon part (Add Part) using advanced editing tools, the area is not updated.

Bug?

Comment: I used version 3.2, after upgrading to 3.4.3 it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I used version 3.2, after upgrading to 3.4.3 it worked!